# how to print a single cell of an array inside a list of arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, console.writeline

I have a list of arrays:

```
List<int[]> a = new List<int[]>();
```

and i put in it a few arrays

```
int[] b = new int[3] {1, 2, 3};
int[] c = new int[4] {4, 5, 6, 7};
a.Add(b);
a.Add(c);
```

how can I print only let's say `b[1]` out of `List a`?

Comment: how about think of this like a grid, and `a[1][1]`, this will return the second item of second array in your list.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar a single int

Comment: You can pin point a position in a `int [,]` just link in a `int [][]`. As you did in your previous code. Give [Jagged Array MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) a quick read.

Comment: Well, `a[0]` gives you the first item in the list `a` (which is `b`), and for `b[1]` you should put `a[0][1]`

Comment: Here is a Quick demo to be clear on the navigation into jagged array: https://dotnetfiddle.net/54M085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it by writing

```
Console.WriteLine(a[0][1]);
```